# Printing values horizontally

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I want to print values horizontally in my report.

For example, I want to print in the following manner:

**A** : 1 2 3 
  **B** : 4 5 6

instead of

**A**
 
    1  
    2  
     3

How can I achieve it?
'A' and 'B' are different columns in the table so I don't think 'crosstab' will work. Or is there anyway to change properties of crosstab to suit my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

go to `properties` set `columns` as 4